# Flutter Navigation Bar - Change tab from another page

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I would like to be able to change the navigation bar tab programmatically. I have a button inside Page1 that navigates to Page2. When I perform this, the navigation bar disappears because I didn't select page2 using the navigation bar.

I have 4 dart files along the lines of navigationbar.dart, page1.dart, page2.dart, page3.dart

The Navigation page is the home page of the application with the children:

```
final List<Widget> _children = [
      Page1(),
      Page2(),
      Page3(),
    ];

return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: _children[_selectedPage],
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(context),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
    );
```

Comment: You want to change the selected tab (navigate to page2) from a button in page1 ? is it true?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Did you solved it? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to change a [TabControlller](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html) like this

1* Create TabController instance

```
TabController _tabController;
```

2* in initState methode use this

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }
```

3* add a Mixin to _HomeState

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {....}
```

4* assign the TabController to your TabBar

```
TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      tabs: _yourTabsHere,
    ),
```

5* Pass controller to your Pages

```
TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children:<Widget> [
  Page1(tabController:_tabController),
  Page2(tabController:_tabController),
  Page3(tabController:_tabController),
];
```

6* call tabController.animateTo() from Page1

```
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
final TabController tabController
Page1({this.tabController});
....}

class _Page1State extends  State<Page1>{
....
onButtonClick(){
  widget._tabController.animateTo(index); //index is the index of the page your are intending to (open. 1 for page2)
}
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Almost headache and found this. This is great! thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using a GlobalKey.

```
var bottomNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<State<BottomNavigationBar>>();
```

put that key in widget,

```js
new BottomNavigationBar(
    key: bottomNavigatorKey,
    items: [...],
   onTap: (int index) {...},
  ),
```

put below lines in change tab method,

```js
BottomNavigationBar navigationBar =  bottomNavigatorKey.currentWidget as BottomNavigationBar;
navigationBar.onTap(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

in the button :

```
onPressed: (){ 
    _currentIndex = 1;
   //or which value you want 
    setState((){});
}
```

in the bottom Navigation bar :

```
currentIndex = _currentIndex
```

Answer (score -1):

You can Use [IndexStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html).

[Demostration.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O0PPD1Xfbk)