# Navigate to a specific page in a specific tab Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, navigator

I am quite new to flutter and I am trying to implement navigation between different tabs.

I am using a CupertinoTabView because I need a parallel navigators and a specific history for each tab in my bottom bar.

My question is whether it is possible to switch from a child page of Tab1 to a child page of Tab2, and if so in which way.
In this image you can see my widget tree:
[image: Widget Tree]

Class **MyApp.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  TabItem _currentTab = TabItem.tab1;

  final Map<TabItem, GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> navigatorKeys = {
    TabItem.tab1: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    TabItem.tab1: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
  };

  Map<TabItem, WidgetBuilder> get widgetBuilders {
    return {
      TabItem.tab1: (_) => Tab1(),
      TabItem.tab2: Tab2(),
    };
  }

  void _select(TabItem tabItem) {
    if (tabItem == _currentTab) {
      navigatorKeys[tabItem].currentState.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
    } else {
      setState(() => _currentTab = tabItem);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoScaffold(
        currentTab: _currentTab,
        onSelectTab: _select,
        widgetBuilders: widgetBuilders,
        navigatorKeys: navigatorKeys,
    );
  }
}
```

Class **CupertinoScaffold.dart** (contains CupertinoTabView)

```
class CupertinoScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const CupertinoScaffold({
    Key key,
    @required this.currentTab,
    @required this.onSelectTab,
    @required this.widgetBuilders,
    @required this.navigatorKeys,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TabItem currentTab;
  final ValueChanged<TabItem> onSelectTab;
  final Map<TabItem, WidgetBuilder> widgetBuilders;
  final Map<TabItem, GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> navigatorKeys;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        key: Key(Keys.tabBar),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(title: Text('Tab1')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(title: Text('Tab2'))
        ],
        onTap: (index) => onSelectTab(TabItem.values[index]),
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        final item = TabItem.values[index];
        return CupertinoTabView(
          navigatorKey: navigatorKeys[item],
          builder: (context) => widgetBuilders[item](context),
          onGenerateRoute: CupertinoTabViewRouter.generateRoute,
        );
      },
    );
  }

}
```

Class **Tab1.dart**

```
class Tab1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Tab1')),
      body: Center(
        child: Button(
          child: Text(
            'Open child tab1'
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/tab1-child'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Class **CupertinoTabViewRouter.dart**

```
class CupertinoTabViewRouter {
  static Route generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/tab1-child':
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => Tab1Child(),
          settings: settings,
          fullscreenDialog: true,
        );
      case '/tab2-child':
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => Tab2Child(),
          settings: settings,
          fullscreenDialog: true,
        );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Class **Tab1Child.dart**

```
class Tab1Child extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('ChildTab1')),
      body: Center(
        child: Button(
          child: Text(
            'Open child tab2'
          ),
          onPressed: () => //TODO!,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This can help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57560751/flutter-navigation-bar-change-tab-from-another-page/57570727#57570727