# Flutter - Update Scaffold Body from Different Tabs

Tags: flutter, tabs, flutter-bottomnavigation, flutter-appbar

On my main Home Tab, I will have a top `TabBar` under the `AppBar` & there will be a bottom navigation bar throughout the majority of the app.

How can I update the `body` based on both tab areas?

The goal would be if I am on the Home Tab, I can update the body from the top tab, but if I tap on a different bottom navigation tab, I need to update to a new Page & NOT show that top `TabBar`.

I'm also using AutoRoute.

Comment: Use Rx or StreamController and listen to changes everywhere you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57560751/flutter-navigation-bar-change-tab-from-another-page may solve your problem or you can create custom function for changed anywhare.